# what means dojo config djConfig.js regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, dojo

While I developing dojo application modules, I meet a regular expression in tutorials.

```
var pathRegex = new RegExp(/\/[^\/]+$/);
var locationPath = location.pathname.replace(pathRegex, '');
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    packages: [
    {
        name: 'modules',
        location: locationPath + '/js/modules'
    }
};
```

What means this regular expression and replacement with path? `RegExp(/\/[^\/]+$/)`

Comment: No offence, but this is a pretty basic expression (there is no need to call the constructor here, either BTW). Just [learn a thing or two about regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), you'll have to sooner or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means to match everything between the last `/` and the end to replace the whole thing with "nothing", meaning to remove it!

```
/my/path/goes/here -> /my/path/goes[/here] -> /my/path/goes
```

**The regex explained**

The outter `/` can be ignored so far. They just mark that there is a RegEx (and some implementations let you add flags after it

Then they want to match `/`. However, `/` has to be escaped as it's a special char. Therefore, they use `\/`.

`[^...]` means everthing except for `...`

Therefore, `[^\/]+` means everything except for `/` multiple times until the end: `$`

However, I really recommend reading up on the basics of regex, as it's going to help you in the future! And it feels really good if you can apply your knowledge, like it always does >:)
Cheers!